# Function not defined when using if else statement

Tags: javascript

when i click the pierre button on the page the image should change, I know the line works but when I press the button it says the function is not defined, I tried changing the ids on the tags but that also didn't work, Im just very confused

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pierre Omidyar</title>
    </head>


<script>
    var x = 0
    function pierre() {
        if (x = 0) {
          document.getElementById('myImage').src='https://cdn3.pitchfork.com/longform/699/Pierre1.jpg'; 
            var x = 1
        } else {
            var x = 0
        }
    } 
</script>
    <body>
        <button onclick="pierre()" type="button">pierre</button>
        <br>
        <img height=50%  width=50% id="myImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0b/Pierre_Omidyar_%2850911249%29.jpg"/>
        <audio loop id="no"><source src="https://codehs.com/uploads/9af74ff56cf4b8ed3809fba276efa59e" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>

    <p id="para">Hi, I'm Pierre Omidyar, I made eBay</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just assigned new value with `=`  ... read  JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: *"... it says the function is not defined"* Do you mean in the developer console it gives that error message? That's surprising given your code. It usually happens when you have a syntax error somewhere, but I don't see one.

Answer (score 0):

The function is called (not `undefined` issue)

There are 2 problems on your code.

1. You have defined `x` variable several times. It's not allowed.
2. `if (x = 0) {` is always false and I think it should be changed to `x == 0`.

Now, this code will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pierre Omidyar</title>
    </head>


<script>
    var x = 0;
    function pierre() {
        if (x == 0) {
          document.getElementById('myImage').src='https://cdn3.pitchfork.com/longform/699/Pierre1.jpg'; 
          x = 1;
        } else {
          x = 0;
        }
    } 
</script>
    <body>
        <button onclick="pierre()" type="button">pierre</button>
        <br>
        <img height=50%  width=50% id="myImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0b/Pierre_Omidyar_%2850911249%29.jpg"/>
        <audio loop id="no"><source src="https://codehs.com/uploads/9af74ff56cf4b8ed3809fba276efa59e" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>

    <p id="para">Hi, I'm Pierre Omidyar, I made eBay</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if (x = 0) {` is always `false`. And it is *allowed* to redeclare the variable. The problem is that the function's `x` is shadowing the global one, even though the function's `var` comes after the `if` condition.

Comment: it is supposed to be a toggle, so x will swap between 0 and 1 everytime the button is pressed, im not sure what you mean by defining it multiple times

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple issues in your code. Here is the updated code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var x = 0;
      function pierre() {
        if (x === 0) {
          document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'https://cdn3.pitchfork.com/longform/699/Pierre1.jpg';
          x = 1
        }
        else {
          x = 0
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="pierre()" type="button">pierre</button>
    <br>
    <img height=50%  width=50% id="myImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0b/Pierre_Omidyar_%2850911249%29.jpg"/>
    <audio loop id="no">
      <source src="https://codehs.com/uploads/9af74ff56cf4b8ed3809fba276efa59e" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <p id="para">Hi, I'm Pierre Omidyar, I made eBay</p>
  </body>
</html>
```